# Can I speed up knockout when populating a large observable array?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a web app that does a SOAP request for some data and populates a knockout viewmodel with the results. I'm currently getting around 1000 line items back that have to be pushed onto my knockout viewmodel. Profiling the page in chrome shows that a large portion of the load time/CPU is spent in knockout.js. I'm wandering if there's a way to maybe delay any knockout updates/processing until all of the items are pushed into the observable array.

**Edit:** To be more clear, I guess I'm looking for something like delaying or [throttling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html). But it looks like, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382789/381422) that I might just be better off building a normal array and then populating the entire observable array, instead of pushing each item directly onto the observable array. This might remove my need to delay or throttle bindings. Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you using ko.mapping?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just need to **replace** the contents of an `observableArray`, you don't need to loop through the array.

The most efficient operation is to simply set it to a new value:

```
this.obsArray(newData);
```

Answer (score 7):

This is probably the best approach:

```
function MyVM(){
    this.fooObsArray = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function Foo(){

var self = this;
self.vm = new MyVM();

this.pushSlow = function(arrayToBePushed){
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToBePushed.length; i++){
        var element = arrayToBePushed[i];
        self.vm.fooObsArray.push(element);          //notifies ui foreach of elements => + delay
    }
}

this.pushFast = function(arrayToBePushed){
    var underlyingArray = self.vm.fooObsArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToBePushed.length; i++){
        var element = arrayToBePushed[i];
        underlyingArray.push(element);
    }

    self.vm.fooObsArray.valueHasMutated();          //notifies ui once all elements have been added => - delay
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am pulling about 850 items into my view model and them displaying them in a select.  Pushing in a loop took about 15 seconds and had linear degradation.

I used the valueHasMutated solution here:  http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Down to about 200ms (overall - including round-trip to server, db read, etc)

Comment: The solution on this page offers a tremendous performance boost, thanks for the Christmas present :) I know it's 2 years late, but if you're still active consider copy/pasting the code so if the page goes offline we still have it at our disposal..

Comment: If it goes offline, you should still be able to see it via archive.org ... https://web.archive.org/web/20150812144018/http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: While I'd prefer to tumble into a discussion, I respectfully disagree. Please view the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer paragraph 'Provide context for links' guidelines. Still, thank you for the solution, it helped me out a lot.

Comment: How are you doing this? I am binding a table with 255 rows and 11 columns, and knockout (version 3.4) needs 1500ms to bind with Chrome and a whopping 4800ms with IE11. I retrieve the data in 80ms, and then it needs twenty times as much time to bind? Before I switched to knockout, I created the row templates manually (construct as string and add with jquery), which was tremendously faster. I am using the vm.obsArray(newArray) approach already.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can make changes in your code, as suggested in the other answers. Another alternative is to use my Deferred Updates plugin: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates

The plugin will automatically delay any updates to the UI (or to any computed observables) until after all changes are done in the current "thread".

Comment: This is now supported natively using extenders or `ko.options.deferUpdates = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another solution is to insert your elements from the array, into the observable array by chunks of 20 or 50 items ?

Since you will be adding items to an observablearray, knockout will display them as you add them, but it might help you reduce the amount of CPU needed, since you will be able to add a delay between each chunk.

Might worth a try.