# Knockout ObservableArray Performance Tweak Needed

Tags: arrays, performance, knockout.js, observable

I am looking to improve the performance of my knockout table binding. My current solution works pretty fast but I am more worried about overhead in the browser due to the web app being ran on an iGel linux terminal utilizing FireFox that comes installed with the OS. The terminals have limited resources and this web app is in a 24x7 production environment.

```
// View Model
self.trMachineData = ko.observableArray([]);
self.machinedata = function () {
  return {
    MachineData_Machine: ko.observable(''),
    MachineData_ProcessDate: ko.observable(''),
    MachineData_Description: ko.observable('')
  };
};

// Page Interactions
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.DisplayData.length; i++) {
  var trd = new vm.machinedata();
  trd.MachineData_Machine(data.d.DisplayData[i].Machine);
  trd.MachineData_ProcessDate(data.d.DisplayData[i].ProcessDate);
  trd.MachineData_Description(data.d.DisplayData[i].Description);
  vm.trMachineData.push(trd);
}

// HTML
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Machine</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: trMachineData">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: MachineData_Machine"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: MachineData_ProcessDate"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: MachineData_Description"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do your MachineData_Machine observables change independently or do they all update at the same time?

Comment: All at the same time.  A barcode is scanned and the web app displays machine process data for an inspector to look at in order to properly disposition the item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I speed up knockout when populating a large observable array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773516/can-i-speed-up-knockout-when-populating-a-large-observable-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need the three items to be observable at all and you can just store them together in one object.
Also, you can update your observable array directly:

```
const tmpData = [] ;
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.DisplayData.length; i++) {
  var trd = {};
  trd.MachineData_Machine = data.d.DisplayData[i].Machine;
  trd.MachineData_ProcessDate = data.d.DisplayData[i].ProcessDate;
  trd.MachineData_Description = data.d.DisplayData[i].Description;
  tmpData.push(trd);
}
vm.trMachineData(data)
```

Then in your table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Machine</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: trMachineData">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: MachineData_Machine"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: MachineData_ProcessDate"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: MachineData_Description"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```